# Different roles and access rights vs. one anon key in Supabase

Tags: postgresql, roles, supabase

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I cannot figure out how roles and access rights to tables  and database work in Supabase. Coming from MongoDB Atlas where it is super easy to define users, their different rights and passwords and then use in front-end accordingly.

My use case is this. I am generating some documents with metadata. These are inserted into Supabase storage (the document) and database table (the metada) using a simple node app.There is a website where the documents and metadata are presented to the public. The website has no user/singing system at all, no need for that, just a simple public website.

Both the node app as well as the website use supabase client with anon key to access Supabase storage and database. The website does not access Supabase storage and database directly but through a server (Sveltekit back-end server.js file to be precise).

My problem is to give website client only the right to read from Supabase. It seems there is no way to have two anon keys with different rights. It seems to me as an overkill to involve Supabase Auth features when there is on need for logging any users. Supabse documentation is silent concerning this use case. To limit anon key on the website just for read and to use service key in the node app seems an inappropriate and dangerous use of service key as well

By the way the default "every one can crud anything in Supabase until you set up row level security" concept of Supabase seems really dangerous and I have serious security concerns if their policies can fix all possible holes.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What is this "simple node app"? Which *users* are using it? How do they authenticate? Is the app also publicly available?

Comment: Thank you very much for your question. As I have said “I am generating …”. so yes it is a private node app run on my own machine without any public availability

Comment: This discussion https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/4547  may bring something to the table  but does not solve my problem.

Comment: I suppose revoking all permissions from `anon` and only granting them `SELECT` is the simplest thing then - you don't need RLS when every user should be able to see everything. Additionally, keep the `anon` key in your Sveltekit backend (instead of publishing it to the frontend) and make Sveltekit only forward GET requests (or not proxy requests at all, just define your own routes and use the supabase client). This add an extra layer of security.

Comment: And yes, using the `service_key` for administration tasks from your private local node app seems like the perfect use case for it. Not sure what you think is inappropriate there.

Comment: Ok. But the service_key usage seems  super overpowered for such a case. This really seems so different from MongoDB Atlas or even Postgres database users system. BTW I can confirm that using the anon key in the backend was my way to go.

Comment: Actually if you're not using RLS on any tables, then `service_key` appears to behave not much different - it's just a different database role.

Answer (score 1):

So my solution was simple. I decided not to use Supabase UI editor at all and pool connected to Supabase database with a direct connection from [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) as adviced in Supaabase [documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/connecting-to-postgres#direct-connections).

From there it was easy do create different users with different rights granted. Just a standard Postgres stuff.  So I have avoided using anon key and supabase client at all.

I guess Supabase documentation does not stress enough that database and storage management form the UI is very strongly coupled with their Auth module which may be often not necessary at all.

Comment: I found a mention of this in https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#you-dont-have-to-use-policies

Comment: As the documentation says:  Supabase is "just Postgres". So I guess my attitude is OK and more easily manageable just a a regular Postgres project.